# Find website URLs that begin with http:// or https://

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex, reinventing-the-wheel

This is a problem from **Automate the Boring Stuff** from "Pattern Matching with Regular Expression". I am a beginner in Python and the purpose of this program is to match urls which start with `http://` or `https://`, with some urls having an optional `www.` after `https://`

How can this code be improved?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#websiteURL.py - Find website URLs that begin with http:// or https://

import pyperclip, re

#protocol Regex - checks for http:// or https://
protocolRegex = re.compile(r'''
    https?://           #match http:// or https://
    (?:w{3}\.)?         #www-dot
    [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+      #domin name
    \.                  #dot
    [a-zA-Z]{2,3}       #extension
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste()) #copying data from document to clipboard and converting it into a string
matches = [] #stores all matches in this list

for website in protocolRegex.findall(text): #finding website from the string text
    matches.append(website)

if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(map(str, matches))) #copying result to clipboard after adding newline after each match
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No website found')
```

Running code:

```
chmod +x websiteURL.py
./websiteURL.py
```

Comment: so `http://www.example.co.uk` is not a valid URL?

Comment: It is is valid.

Comment: Oh, because `findall` and not `match`, right. But this is confusing from the regex alone…

Answer (score 3):

## Variable Names

Variables should be lower-cased and snake-case, meaning that multiple words should look like `some_variable`, not `someVariable` or `SomeVariable`. I think the name you've chosen for your regex is good and expresses exactly what it is:

```py
protocol_regex = re.compile(...)
```

## Checking length of a list/container data structure

It is not considered pythonic to check the emptiness of a container in python by using `if len(container) == 0`, most* containers have a `__bool__` method built-in that allows you to do `if not container` for an empty one and `if container` for non-empty:

```py
from collections import deque

if not {}:
    print("empty dict")
empty dict

if not []:
    print("empty list")
empty list

if not '':
    print("empty string")
empty string

if not deque():
    print("empty deque")
empty deque

if ['result1']:
    print('non-empty list')
non-empty list
```

One of the few that does *not* behave this way is [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), which I've included to give context to the *most* comment.

With this in mind, change your `match` check to:

```py
if matches:
    # rest of code
else:
    # else code here
```

Comment: Your point on multi-line strings and the regex would usually be correct, but not in this case: the `re.VERBOSE` flag makes sure that whitespace is ignored and comments are possible, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE

Comment: @RafG ooo, missed that one. Time for some reading. Good catch, I'll make an edit

Comment: @RafG I suppose that raises a question, is it better practice to use `re.VERBOSE` and triple-quote your regex, or to use parentheses and break up the raw strings for multiline statements? Asking for my own enrichment here

Comment: There are some advantages to breaking up the raw strings for sure: syntax highlighting to more easily distinguish comments and no need to escape whitespace characters if the regex contains any. On the other hand,`re.VERBOSE` feels less 'heavy' to me (admittedly this is very subjective) and is somewhat more flexible. E.g., you can 'indent' parts of your regex to make the structure clearer ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955966/183054)), the string with the regex and comments can be loaded from a file, etc.

Comment: Loading the regex from a file seems extremely advantageous. Never knew that could be a use case, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression is inadequate for real domain names.  Here's a few actual examples that fail:

```
http://hes.scot/
https://WWW.historicenvironment.scot/
https://www.bbc.co.uk
https://WWW.BBC.CO.UK
```

These are extracted as

```
http://hes.sco
https://WWW.his
https://www.bbc.co
https://WWW.BBC
```

Domain names are case-insensitive, can contain any number of levels, and need not end in a component having 2 or 3 letters.

(Note that the *scheme* name - `http` or `https` - *is* case-sensitive, as is the local part of a URL).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for reinvention of the wheel and complex pattern matching.
Use `urllib.parse.urlparse` to check for the URL's scheme.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_http_or_https(url):
    return urlparse(url).scheme in {'http', 'https'}
```

Comment: That might be true, but the OP took this from a book to learn Python coding by example, and I'm pretty sure "use a library" was not the main goal of that chapter.

Comment: I am here to review given code to help improve it. If some random coding learning book insists on not using libraries designed to solve a specific problem, the best purpose it can serve is as a combustible.

Comment: No need to get destructive here. The author chose to use the URL scheme as an example to learn something about regular expressions. One might argue if that is the best example to teach them, but it's certainly a recognizable one.

Comment: Yes, you can offer that feedback, however I think it's easy to argue that this suggestion really doesn't improve the code or its intended use. Especially given that it's tagged *reinventing-the-wheel*, showing that OP specifically intends to circumvent existing libraries to work on a specific skill, which in this case is regex